# Pegar todo o texto de uma linha digitada

Tags: c, scanf

Estou criando um algoritmo em C para treinar mesmo e preciso pegar um texto (grande e com espaços) que o usuário digitar no prompt mesmo.
Eu tentei usando scanf, gets e fgets e nenhum está pegando o que vem depois do espaço, apenas o texto até chegar no primeiro espaço.
Como eu consigo pegar todo o texto e guardar em um array de char apenas ?

```
char texto[3000];
fgets(texto, 3000, stdin);
```

Minha última tentativa foi esta, mas ele pega só a primeira palavra antes do espaço.

Saliento que não pode pegar enter (quebra de linha) pois existem mais ações a serem feitas após pegar o primeiro texto

Comment: Testei aqui e pegou as palavras apos o espaço

Answer (score 3):

Fiz esse teste aqui e ele leu a linha inteira. Como você está verificando o valor lido? Pode ser que o erro esteja nessa parte.

Veja o meu código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char texto[3000];
    fgets(texto, 3000, stdin);
    printf("%s", texto);

    return 0;
}
```